# Computer System not starting after trying to Install Ubuntu along with already installed Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, shutdown

Computer System not starting after trying to install ubuntu alongside Windows

1. Created a bootable pen drive using another computer with the aid of Rufus software
2. Attached the pen drive to my computer and started the system
3. Before the system started pressed esc+ F9 then ubuntu option selected
4. There was 1 error flashed in a second which i couldn't take note of but went away but the process went on as per videos shown on YouTube till step before country time selection.
5. In partition of disk space, reduced windows space of around 62 to 63 gb (approx.) which was showing by default to 61.2 gb out of 122.4 gb appearing on top right for giving equal space to ubuntu and windows and clicked install.
6. Ubuntu did not install and opened in live ubuntu mode. Live ubuntu worked properly.
   So tried installing ubuntu agin through option appearing on desktop.
7. This time but the system did not work after clicking install ubuntu as specified in pt 5 steps. where i think it became hang. So had to shut the pc forcefully.
8. Restarted the pc, it displayed preparing automatic repair but suddenly screen went black as if pc is shut down but still small white light next to power button still flashing.
9. I pressed power button again, the screen turns on but shuts down again with black screen. Even if i try pressing esc button immediately after power button, the system goes to showing f8, f9,...option but before i could do any, the system goes down with white small light near power button still flashing. Even tried pressing F10 immediately after power option but still as i enter BIOS setup, the system goes down as if the system goes down immediately within 5 seconds of whatever task you try to perform.

Comment: Did you disable UEFI- ? and fast boot? before the installation? I think you accidentally installed it at the wrong space.  Did you take a backup of your important files before the ubuntu installation?

Comment: @saviour 123, followed your advice, now that problem is solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check the main answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to UEFI and Fastboot.

On newer computers, before you dualboot windows with ubuntu, you need to get into BIOS and Disable UEFI or set it to Legacy Mode in the BIOS.
Second, look for fast boot and disable it.

Important- Backup critical files.